# Google won't duplicate the active sheet using "duplicateActiveSheet();"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

### Code:

```
ss.setActiveSheet(template);   
Browser.msgBox("Set Active Sheet");  
ss.dupliacteActiveSheet();   
Browser.msgBox("Duplicated Sheet");  
ss.deleteSheet(sheet);   
Browser.msgBox("Deleted Old Sheet");  
ss.moveActiveSheet(1);   
Browser.msgBox("Moved Sheet");  
ss.renameActiveSheet("Timesheet2");   
Browser.msgBox("Renamed Sheet");
```

I just don't understand...I am looking to replace a sheet with its template every week. I have set a time trigger to the above function... When I run the function I get to the "Set active sheet" popup but my code doesn't seem to go any further. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly did my question get downvoted? I will take any suggestions on how else to delete a sheet and replace it with a template...

Comment: Instead of using `Browser.msgBox();`, an alternative is to use `Logger.log('some text here: ' + variableName);` statements, and then VIEW the LOGS.

Comment: Don't know who gave the down-vote:  Maybe because there are similar questions:  [Stack Overflow - Duplicate Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781758/google-apps-duplicate-template-sheet-and-delete-old-sheet?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This line has a misspelled function name, (duplicate):

```
ss.dupliacteActiveSheet();
```

Should be:

```
ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
```

In the VIEW menu of the code editor, check the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT.  There will probably be an error msg there.